# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

While I tried to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 using the command - `sudo update-manager -d` , the message "the software in this computer is uptodate" is shown. How can I upgrade it to 16.04?

Comment: You need to fully update your current release first: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get full-upgrade".

Answer (score 0):

`sudo update-manager -d` only update current release.

You can try with following command in terminal.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Follow the instructions guided by upgrade tool.

Comment: while giving the command ,the message " No new release found" is seen

Comment: According to this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts), *"upgrades between LTS releases are not enabled by default until the first point release"* can't upgrade directly. But currently 16.04.1 is released. So I suppose to be OK with this command.

Comment: [This guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts) also point out, you need to be update to upgrade notification available.

Answer (score 0):

What I did: 
-in "Software and Updates" open the "Updates" tab
-the bottom line gives the upgrade option to select the type of Ubuntu version, 
- select "For Long-time support version" 
- next auto update will select 16.04LTS to download and asks your premission for installation.